# combine two select statements (append columns)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, wp-cli

I have 2 Wordpress database queries, the first shows all posts + categories. The second shows all posts + custom fields.

What I'm looking for is listing all posts + categories + custom fields

Query 1: list posts + categories

```
SELECT ID,
post_title,

(SELECT group_concat(wp_terms.name separator ", ") FROM wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on wp_terms.term_id = 
wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr on wpr.term_taxonomy_id = 
wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE taxonomy="category" and wp_posts.ID = wpr.object_id ) AS 
"Categories"
FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish"

+------+--------------------------------------+------------+
| ID   | post_title                           | Categories |
+------+--------------------------------------+------------+
```

Query 2: list posts + custom fields

```
SELECT ID, post_title, pm1.meta_value as "Amazon.com", pm2.meta_value 
as "Amazon.co.uk" FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ID = pm1.post_id AND 
pm1.meta_key = "Amazon.com"
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON ID = pm2.post_id AND 
pm2.meta_key = "Amazon.co.uk"
WHERE post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish"

+------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID   | post_title            | Amazon.com   | Amazon.co.uk |
+------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

How can I combine the results so that I can list all posts + categories + custom fields?

```
+------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID   | post_title  | Categories  | Amazon.com   | Amazon.co.uk |
+------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: You can create two different views and combine it later using joins, Can it be a solution ?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `UNION ALL`  and have default placeholders for the columns, so they all appear in one query

Comment: Do you want to return one row per `ID`?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following query:

```
SELECT ID, post_title, pm1.meta_value as "Amazon.com", pm2.meta_value as "Amazon.co.uk" , 
                                        (SELECT group_concat(wp_terms.name separator ", ") FROM wp_terms
                                        INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on wp_terms.term_id = 
                                        wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
                                        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr on wpr.term_taxonomy_id = 
                                        wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
                                        WHERE taxonomy="category" and wp_posts.ID = wpr.object_id ) AS "Categories"
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ID = pm1.post_id AND 
pm1.meta_key = "Amazon.com"
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON ID = pm2.post_id AND 
pm2.meta_key = "Amazon.co.uk"
WHERE post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish"
```

Comment: He's got a `LEFT JOIN` on there so it's likely it's a one to many relationship. Did you mean to throw a `GROUP_CONCAT()` on the `meta_value` columns?

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina The subquery is to get all categories related to the post, it is not related to the left joins.

Comment: Roger that, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all the columns in the same result is to 'merge' the two queries together and `SELECT` the unique columns listed in each of the queries.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  post_title,
  (SELECT 
     GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.name SEPARATOR ", ") 
   FROM 
     wp_terms
     INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on wp_terms.term_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
     INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr on wpr.term_taxonomy_id= wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
   WHERE 
     taxonomy="category"   
     AND wp_posts.ID=wpr.object_id 
  ) AS `Categories`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(pm1.meta_value) AS `Amazon.com`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(pm2.meta_value) AS `Amazon.co.uk`
FROM 
  wp_posts 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS `pm1` ON pm1.post_id=ID AND pm1.meta_key="Amazon.com"
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS `pm2` ON pm2.post_id=ID AND pm2.meta_key="Amazon.co.uk"
WHERE 
  post_type="post" 
  AND post_status="publish"
GROUP BY
  ID;
```

Let me know if there are any problems.

Hope this helps,

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output. Not sure there is a need for GROUP_CONCAT on the meta_value fields. Each meta_key only holds 1 value.